# What is a solution for multiple inheritance - with opportunity to change protection?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I need a solution for multiple inheritance. I know that I can use interfaces. That would be good solution but...

I need opportunity to change protection level but fields of interface must be public.

For example:

I have

```
interface IInterface_1 {
  string field_1{set;get;}
  string field_2{set;get;}
}

interface IInterface_2 {
  string field_3{set;get}
  string field_4{set;get}
}
```

And in main class I need to hide some fields

```
class MainClass : IInterface_1, IInterface_2 {
  public string field_1{set;get;}
  private string field_2{set;get;}
  public string field_3{set;get}
  public string field_4{set;get}
}
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: can I convince you to make the edit an *answer* rather than part of the *question*?

Comment: Of course. I already did it. You have to accept the edit.

Comment: I think Marc meant as a separate answer; he could have edited your answer into his post on his own.  I have done this for you.  The downside of me doing it is that you cannot get reputation for it (I won't either), but that also applied to you tacking it on to Marc's answer.  Note that your edit was rejected by the community (not be Marc).

Comment: Ok. I cant answer for my questions. That is reason why I didnt this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Copied from Robson's question and his rejected edit to Marc's answer]**

My solution is:

```
public class PermissionDeniedException : Exception {}

class MainClass : IInterface_1, IInterface_2 {
  public string field_1{set;get;}
  private string field_2{set;get;}
  string IInterface_1.field_2 {
    get {throw new PermissionDeniedException();}
    set {throw new PermissionDeniedException();}
  }
  public string field_3{set;get}
  public string field_4{set;get}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Explicit interface implementation:

```
 class MainClass : IInterface_1, IInterface_2 {        
    public string field_1{get;set;}
    public string field_3{get;set;}
    public string field_4{get;set;}

    private string field2;
    string IInterface_1.field_2 {
        get {return field2;}
        set {field2 = value;}
    }
 }
```

Comment: var x = new MainClass();  ((IInterface_1)x).field_2 = -1;  That will still get to that member though...  suppose you could make IInterface_1 internal also?

Comment: @Nathan - changing protection is only ever hiding. You can always do that, even with "full" MI

Comment: Yes I saw this solution but you still can get this value. I need to revoke this permission completely.

Comment: @robson - then it can't be part of a public interface; the interface *could* be protected to some set of subclasses, or private to some set of nested classes, but in all honesty it probably isn't worth it. Anyone who cared can use reflection to get at your field.